# How to Set Selected Index value on after reload the JSP Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

```
<select id="blkType" onchange="submitCnt('<%=prdctDetLclId%>')" name="selectVal">
    <option value="0">Select</option> 
    <option value="1">All Active Bookings</option> 
    <option value="2">All Active Reservations</option>
    <option value="3">All Expired</option>
    <option value="4">Previous Year</option>
    <option value="5">Current Year</option>
```

How to set The selected Value After Page Load

Answer (score 0):

Setting values on a `<select>` is done through the following code :

```
document.getElementById("blkType").selectedIndex = YOUR_INDEX_GOES HERE;
```

Put your `<script>` at the very end of your Document if you want it to be executed last.